# cannot pass parameter to twig template in symfony 4

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

I'm having difficulties passing 2 parameters from a controller to the twig template to render a form.
Symfony keeps telling me *"Variable error does not exist."*
Now, tested and confirmed that even the variable *"error"* ,*"last_username"* is defined in the controller is not reaching the template! 
Just don't understand why...even went over all my config files...

Ironically I'm also using the same code in another mini app and is working FINE!

what am I missing?

controller code:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationUtils;

class SecurityController
{   
    /**
     * @var \Twig_Environment
     */
    private $twig;

    public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig)
    {
        $this->twig = $twig;
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="security_login")
     */
    public function login(AuthenticationUtils $authenticationUtils)
    {
        return new Response($this->twig->render(
            'security/login.html.twig',
            [
                'last_username'=> $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername(),
                'error'=> $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError(),
            ]
         ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/logout", name="security_logout")
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        # code...
    }
}
```

The twig template:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    {% if  error %}
        <div class="alert alert-danger">
            {{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}
        </div>
    {% endif %}

    <div class="container">
        <form action="{{ path('security_login') }}" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label" for="username">User Name</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="username" name="_username" required="required"  value="{{ last_username }}" aria-describedby="user name">
                <small id="userNameHelp" class="form-text text-muted">This will be your login name!.</small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label required" for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="_password" required="required" placeholder="Password">
            {# </div>
                <div class="form-group form-check">
                <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">Im aMuppet and forgot my password...</label>
            </div> #}
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="Login" name="Login">Submit</button>
        </div>

        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token"  value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
        <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="{{ app.request.get('redirect_to') }}">>

        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: why not return variables directly?
        return $this->render('security/login.html.twig', [
            'last_username'=> $authenticationUtils->getLastUsername(),
            'error'=> $authenticationUtils->getLastAuthenticationError(),
            ]);

Comment: Are you sure that the template is rendered by the controller above? Maybe some other controller is executed that does not populate these variables.

Comment: Thank you Phillip, tried it but with no luck ... i must be doing something wrong somewhere else i guess...

Comment: @ xabbuh Fair point  wish I knew what that would may be ... is there a logic i  can use to trace it backwards ? ( I' m a newbie)